# Time reversal effect on time derivative in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry

I am reading Zee's *Quantum field theory in a nutshell.* On time reversal he has

> Consider the transformation $t\rightarrow t'= -t$. We want to find $\Psi'(t')$ such that  $i(\partial/\partial t′)\Psi′( t′) = H\Psi'(t′)$. Write $\Psi′(t′) = T\Psi(t)$, where $T$ is some operator to be determined (up to some arbitrary phase factor $\eta$). Plugging in, we have $i[ \partial/ \partial( − t)] T\Psi( t) = HT\Psi( t)$. Multiply by $T^{-1}$, and we obtain $T^{ − 1}( − i) T( \partial/ \partial t)\Psi( t) = T^{−1}HT( t)\Psi(t)$.

My question is: Has he assumed that $T$ and $\partial/\partial t$ commute and if so why is it valid to do that?

Comment: Maybe it is Group theory in a nutshell, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider derivative at $t=0$; denote $\Psi(0)$ as $\Psi_{0}$

$(\partial /\partial t)T\Psi(t)\big|_{t=0}=\displaystyle lim_{h\rightarrow0}((T\Psi_{0})(h)-T\Psi_{0})/h$

Since $T\Psi$ evolves according to
 $i(\partial /\partial (-t))T\Psi(t)=HT\Psi(t)$

So $(T\Psi_{0}) (h)= exp(ihH)T\Psi_{0}$. Hence we have :

$\displaystyle lim_{h\rightarrow0}((T\Psi_{0})(h)-T\Psi_{0})/h$

$=\displaystyle lim_{h\rightarrow0}(exp(iHh)(T\Psi_{0})-T\Psi_{0})/h$

$=\displaystyle lim_{h\rightarrow0}(Texp(-iHh)\Psi_{0}-T\Psi_{0})/h$   $\:\:\;\;\;$(Since $T$ and $H$ commute, and $T$ is antilinear)

$=\displaystyle lim_{h\rightarrow0}T(exp(-iHh)\Psi_{0}-\Psi_{0})/h$

$=T(\partial /\partial t)\Psi(t)\big|_{t=0}$

Notation : $(T\Psi_{0})(h)$ means we first act $\Psi_{0}$ by $T$ and then time evolve the resulting state by an amount of time $h$.

**Another argument** : following argument seems more relevant here than above one :-

We have a one parameter family of states $\Psi(t)$ which satisfy

$i(\partial /\partial (t))\Psi(t)=H\Psi(t)$

For definiteness suppose $t\in[0,1]$, and suppose we partition this interval into $N$ equal parts (where $N$ is some large number) as {$0=t_0<t_1<....<t_{N-1}<t_N=1$}. Denote $\Psi (t_j)$ as $\Psi_j$ for $j=0,...,N$, and let $1/N=\delta$ (length of one small interval).Then above differential equation can be written as a set of $N$ linear equations in terms of states $\Psi_j$'s as :

$i(\Psi_1-\Psi_0)/\delta=H\Psi_0$

$i(\Psi_2-\Psi_1)/\delta=H\Psi_1$

....

$i(\Psi_j-\Psi_{j-1})/\delta=H\Psi_{(j-1)}$

....

$i(\Psi_N-\Psi_{(N-1)})/\delta=H\Psi_{(N-1)}$

Now in Zee's book the one parameter family of vectors $T\Psi(t)$  is required to
satisfy the differential equation $-i(\partial /\partial t)T\Psi(t)=HT\Psi(t)$. 
Or in discretised form it is required that the set of vectors $T\Psi_0,T\Psi_1,.....,T\Psi_N$ satisfy following linear equations :

$-i(T\Psi_1-T\Psi_0)/\delta=HT\Psi_0$

$-i(T\Psi_2-T\Psi_1)/\delta=HT\Psi_1$

....

$-i(T\Psi_j-T\Psi_{j-1})/\delta=HT\Psi_{(j-1)}$

....

$-i(T\Psi_N-T\Psi_{(N-1)})/\delta=HT\Psi_{(N-1)}$

Now since $T$ is linear wrt addition of states so it can be taken out:

$-iT(\Psi_1-\Psi_0)/\delta=HT\Psi_0$

$-iT(\Psi_2-\Psi_1)/\delta=HT\Psi_1$

....

$-iT(\Psi_j-\Psi_{j-1})/\delta=HT\Psi_{(j-1)}$

....

$-iT(\Psi_N-\Psi_{(N-1)})/\delta=HT\Psi_{(N-1)}$

In continuum limit these equations are equivalent to :

$-iT(\partial /\partial t)\Psi(t)=HT\Psi(t)$

---

**Edit :**

Question: Consider a one parameter family of states $\Psi(t)$ which satisfy Schrodinger equation $i(\partial /\partial t)\Psi(t)=H\Psi(t)$. Is it possible to find an invertible linear operator $T$ that commutes with $H$ and such that for any $\Psi(t)$ as above, $T\Psi(t)$ satisfies $-i(\partial /\partial t)T\Psi(t)=HT\Psi(t)$ ?

Our previous argument (2nd one) extends to one proof that it is not possible; Here is another one :

If $T$ is such an operator then $T\Psi(t)=exp(itH)T\Psi(0)$. (because $T\Psi(t)$ solves time reversed Schr. equation) -----(1)

Also $\Psi(t)=exp(-itH)\Psi(0)$ (Because $\Psi(t)$ solves usual Schr. equation).
          -------(2)

Substituting (2) into (1) we get $Texp(-itH)\Psi(0)=exp(itH)T\Psi(0)$

Now using the fact that T is invertible we get :

$exp(-itH)\Psi(0)=T^{-1}exp(itH)T\Psi(0)$

Again using the fact that $T$ is linear and commutes with $H$ we get

$exp(-itH)\Psi(0)=exp(itH)\Psi(0)$ (note that if $T$ were antilinear then in place of $exp(itH)$ on RHS we would have $exp(-itH)$, and hence there would be no problem)

Now multiplying on both sides with $exp(-itH)$ we get

$exp(-2itH)\Psi(0)=\Psi(0)$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ and putting $t=0$ we get

$H\Psi(0)=0$

But $\Psi(0)$ was any arbitrary state in our space of states. So we have $H=0$ identically. Hence the required linear operator is not possible unless $H$ vanishes identically.

Comment: @physicsphile i have made some corrections.

Comment: I think that is right, I suppose the bottom line is that T takes the complex conjugate of what it is operating on and $\partial/\partial t$ is real. But I don't quite follow the logic of Zee's presentation of it. I think it would be worth removing your first argument as you pointed out it is not correct as T will change the sign of the exponential

Comment: i don't understand why first argument is incorrect. i have checked it many times and it seems to be correct; only problem is that it will go through for linear $T$ as well. Anyway, if i found that its incorrect i will remove it.

Comment: $\Psi(t)$ evolves according to usual Schrodinger equation and so $\Psi(t)=exp(-itH)\Psi_0$.

Comment: Here $T\Psi$ is required to satisfy time reversed form of Schrodinger equation, which is of the  form $-i(\partial/\partial t)(T\Psi)(t) = HT\Psi(t)$. So solution for this equation would be of the form $T\Psi(t)=exp(itH)T\Psi_0$.

Comment: Zee's idea is to prove that $T$ is antilinear; and as i mentioned first argument doesn't lead us to any conclusion about that. If you assume that T is linear and commutes with H, then following first argument you will get $(\partial/\partial t)T\Psi=-T(\partial/\partial t)\Psi$; and using this it can again be shown that $T\Psi$ will satisfy the time reversed Schrodinger equation that it is required to satisfy. However this is not the case with second argument. Here T definitely has to be antilinear once we require that it satifies time reversed Schr. eq and commutes with H.

Comment: @physicsphile I have added one more argument just to make sure that you are not carried away by seeming correctness of first argument. First argument seems circular and doesn't prove anything; however i will not delete it for we learn something from such arguments too.

Comment: Regarding the initial question:partial derivative w.r.t time  has nothing to do with time reversal because the derivative does not 'care' if time is negative ,it just measures the change of the function it  acts upon .Hence they should commute.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
This is just an initial reasoning as I am diving into literature.