# Does the time inversion operator commute or anticommute with the total time derivative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm wonderdering if the time reversal operator $T$ commutes or anticommutes with the time derivative operator. On one hand I think they commute, because
$$
T \frac {\text d} {\text d t} f(t) 
= 
T \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(t+\Delta) - f(t)}{\Delta} 
\overset{\text{hope so}}= 
\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} T \frac {f(t+\Delta) - f(t)}{\Delta} 
=
\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac {f^*(t+\Delta) - f^*(t)}{\Delta^*} 
\\
\overset{t \in \mathbb R}
=
\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac {f^*(t+\Delta) - f^*(t)}{\Delta} 
=
\frac {\text d}{\text d t} T f(t)
$$
for every function $f(t)$.

On the other hand for every valid wavefunction $f(x,t)$ the Schrodinger Equation
$$
i \hbar \frac {\text d}{\text d t} f(x,t) = H f(x,t)
$$
holds, which means that I can replace $H$ with $i \hbar \frac {\text d}{\text d t}$ when acting on a valid wavefunction.
If we now have a system that has time reversal invariance, we know that the Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with the time reversal operator, which means that
$$
i \hbar \frac {\text d}{\text d t} T 
= 
H T
=
TH
=
T i \hbar \frac {\text d}{\text d t} 
=
-i \hbar T \frac {\text d}{\text d t} 
$$
which means that $T$ and $\frac {\text d} {\text d t}$ anticommute.

What am I doing wrong? What is the (anti)commutation rule for the time reversal operator and the time derivative?

Comment: Nice question (+1), but it seems to me that it is a duplicate of [Time reversal effect on time derivative in Quantum Mechanics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35477/time-reversal-effect-on-time-derivative-in-quantum-mechanics?rq=1), don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is wrong. Define $g = Tf$. Applying the basic differentiation rule $(u \circ v)'(t) = u'(v(t))v'(t)$ for composed functions to $g(t)=f^*(-t)$, we have $$(Tf)'(t)=g'(t)\overset{\text{rule}}=-(f^*)'(-t)=-(f')^*(-t)=-(T(f'))(t)$$ for all $t$, hence $(Tf)' = -T(f')$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if you define $g:=Tf$ then $g(t)=f^*(t)$ and not $f(-t)$.

Comment: Isn't time inversion changing $t$ in $-t$? See for example [T-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry).

Comment: No. The operator which in the literature is called "time inversion operator" is just an antiunitary operator under which spatial eigenstates are invariant, i.e. $T | x \rangle = | x \rangle$. If $f(x,t)$ is a wavefunction, then $Tf(x,t) = f^*(x,t)$. Inversion of the temporal argument is neccessary to obtain a "physical" wavefunction, but it's not the job of the time inversion operator.

Comment: Are you sure about the sign of $t$? This [reference](http://phys.columbia.edu/~cyr/notes/Quantum_2/lecture4.pdf) says $Tf(x,t)=f^{∗}(x,-t)$. I was considering real $f$ in my answer, but the result remains the same for non-real $f$.

Comment: @psicolor I added the conjugate case to my answer to make it correct for all complex valued functions. As you can see, the conclusion remains the same:  $(Tf)′=−T(f′)$.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the reference, but i have to admit that this is the common case. The naming as "time inversion operator" is  misleading, a more handy name would be "impulse inversion operator", but for historical reasons, everyone uses the first. The reference says, that the symmetry operation which reverses time maps $f(x,t)$ to $f^*(x,-t)$. This is correct, but it is not, what the time inversion operator (which should be better called "impulse inversion operator") does.

Comment: I don't see how what you say connects to the [T-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) reference I mentioned earlier which says "In theoretical physics, T-symmetry is the theoretical symmetry of physical laws under a time reversal transformation: $ T : t \mapsto - t$". Maybe you could point to a reference which mentions explicitely that $ t \mapsto t$ under time reversal (or time inversion)?

Comment: You are right that time inversion maps $t \rightarrow -t$, but the operator which is called "time inversion operator" or "time reversal operator" does not! If $\psi(x,t)$ is a valid wavefunction, then the time reversed wavefunction is $T \psi(x,-t) = \psi^*(x,-t)$. The reference you mentioned explains that. Read it again, but keep in mind that the actual inversion of the temporal argument is not what the "time reversal operator" does. The time reversal operator just inverses velocities, nothing more. To get a movie that makes sense, you additionaly have to invert the $t$ argument.

Comment: Well then how comes the discrepency of your question? Besides, I find it strange that if the only action of $T$ is to take the conjugate (that's all it does in your question), no need of specific operator, just use the conjugate function. BTW, I don't see what you mention in the reference I gave, where is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47993/discussion-between-claude-chuber-and-psicolor).