# Why does time reversal symmetry requires a real Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, complex-numbers, time-reversal-symmetry

I have some problems understanding the consequences of time reversal symmetry.

If Hamiltonian $H$ is symmetric under time reversal, it satisfies:

$$
 \mathcal{T} H \mathcal{T}^{-1} = H \quad \mathrm{with} \quad \mathcal{T} = U \mathcal{K} \\
 U H^{*} = H U \mathcal{K} \\
H^{*} = U^{-1} H U K .
$$
But how does one obtain for a general case $$ H^{*} = H~?$$
It would be very nice, if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: It's much easier to get good answers on a clear question. What are $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{U}$, and $\mathcal{K}$?

Comment: The correct condition is $H^*=U^{-1}HU$ without the $K$. It doesn't always mean $H^*=H$.

Comment: Sorry. In retrospective the operators in my question are not well defined.  $ \mathcal{T} $ is the time reversal operator, which can be expressed as $U \mathcal{K}$ since its antiunitary. $U$ is an unitary operator and $\mathcal{K} $ the complex conjugation operator.

Answer (score 2):

If $\ \ \mathcal{T}\mathcal {H} \mathcal{T}^{-1} = \mathcal {H}\implies \mathcal{TH}=\mathcal{HT}$ where $\mathcal{T=UK}$ with $\mathcal K$ denoting complex conjugation, then if we apply this to an arbitrary state $\psi$  $$\mathcal{TH}\psi=\mathcal{HT}\psi$$ $$\rightarrow \mathcal{UKH}\psi=\mathcal{HUK}\psi$$

$$\rightarrow \mathcal{KH}\psi=\mathcal{U^{-1}HUK}\psi\tag1$$

$$\rightarrow \mathcal{H^*}\psi^*=\mathcal{U^{-1}}\mathcal{HU}\psi^*$$

so that in the *general* case, $$\rightarrow \mathcal{H^*}=\mathcal{U^{-1}}\mathcal{HU}$$ so that the complex conjugate of the Hamiltonian is *unitarily equivalent* to the Hamiltonian.

1. In the case where $[\mathcal H,\mathcal U]=0$ i.e., $\mathcal U$ is a symmetry of the system, we could from equation (1) write $$\rightarrow \mathcal{UKH}\psi=\mathcal{UHK}\psi$$ $$\rightarrow \mathcal{KH}\psi=\mathcal{U^{-1}UHK}\psi$$ then $$\mathcal{H^*}\psi^*=\mathcal{H}\psi^*$$ since $\mathcal{U^{-1}U}=\mathbb I$
   which then implies $$\mathcal H^*=\mathcal H$$ meaning $\mathcal H$ is real.
2. Example: In the case of spinless particles, $\mathcal U$ is chosen to be the identity operator $\mathbb I$ so that $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal {UK}=\mathcal K$ (or that time reversal corresponds to simple complex conjugation of the wave
   function for a *spinless* particle) and so if the system has time-reversal symmetry: $$ [\mathcal H,\mathcal T]=0 \implies \mathcal [\mathcal H,\mathcal K]=0 \implies\mathcal {KH}\psi=\mathcal {HK}\psi$$
   which leads to
   $$\mathcal H^*\psi^*=\mathcal H\psi^*$$
   again meaning that the Hamiltonian must be real.

Comment: I guess your argument is only valid when $\mathcal{U}$ is a symmetry of the system which is not the case in general.

Comment: $U$ does not have to commute with $H$.

Comment: That's true in _general_. I have made an edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your have a mistake in the second line $U \mathcal K H = U H^* \mathcal K$ (not $U H^*$). It therefore follows that
$$ U H^* \mathcal K = H U \mathcal K \Leftrightarrow H^* = U^{-1} H U. $$
This means, the Hamiltonian is not strictly real, but it is unitarily equivalent to its complex conjugate (which is the next-best thing).
See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622768/276737) question on the topic.

Let me know if there are further questions or mistakes!